# Windows phone 8, web browser control is opening media files with media element and navigate from application

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

Is there a way to detect on WP8 that web browser control is automatically opening media files using media player which then activate  OnNavigateFrom event, and how to differ  that event from  OnNavigateFrom event that is activated when  backBtn,Start or search button pressed.
This is important  because different code need to be activated in those cases. 
Is there a way to detect when web browser control is selecting URL that is some kind of media URL, and to prevent URL to be  open in external application, but to open URL in web browser control or some media element that is existing in application?

Answer (score 0):

You can override OnBackKeyPress Event. 
Define a static Boolean variable in App.xaml.cs, initialize it false.
and set this true when back key is pressed.

and set it to false when OnNavigateTo event is fired

Answer (score 0):

You will need to do http communication to the uri. Then, on inspecting the response, you will be able to have a clear idea about the url type , i.e either browser web page or a media URL opening in a separate media player.

The RequestContext class , that you will be using for http communication ,contains information about the HTTP request in the HttpContext property. When you construct a URL from a route, you pass an instance of the RequestContext class to the RouteCollection.GetVirtualPath method.

If you see that requestContext.response.MediaType is either text/html or text/plain or image/svg+xml or application/xhtml+xml , then the url is browsable one, 
else for any other mime type, the browser will open default apps like the media player or the unzip utility depending upon the type of url.

This is how i had segregated the browsable uris and the downloadable uris.

```
    private bool IsBrowsableMimeType(RequestContext requestContext)
    {
        //If the mime is text/html or text/plain or image/svg+xml or application/xhtml+xml
        //then mime type is browsable
        //else it is downloadable
        if (requestContext.response.MediaType == null)
        {
            return true;
        }
        if (!requestContext.response.MediaType.Equals("text/html") && !requestContext.response.MediaType.Equals("text/plain") && !requestContext.response.MediaType.Equals("application/xhtml+xml") && !requestContext.response.MediaType.Equals("image/svg+xml"))
        {
            //If the url is of image mime type, then let the browser show the image, dont download it.
            if (!requestContext.response.MediaType.Equals("image/svg+xml") && requestContext.response.MediaType.Contains("image"))
            {
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
        else
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
```

This is how i had achieved it.

Comment: On which event did you try HTTP communication, because when I select Uri that represent link to video in from web browse  control i can't get any event(like navigation or similar...)I just get event On Navigation From App from which I cant get any useful data.So what is the event on which you are creating HTTP communication to determent which MIME type uri you want to go to is having?

Comment: Browser control has an event "Navigating", which fires when the browser is navigating to any uri. You can have the check there. But, this event fires several times automatically unless the browser successfully navigates to the uri.

After the Navigating event has fired several times, there are events like "Navigated" and  "Navigation Completed" which get fired in the end.

Actually, you could carry out this check for the uri even before setting the uri to the browser for navigation. First carry out the check for Mime and then set it to browser.
Hope i am taking you in the right direction.

Comment: Moreover, the "navigating" event also fires several times in the case of internal re-directions for uris.

Comment: Don't know if you try this on any page that has some links to video, because when you chose video link from page, web browsing component don't  fire navigation event also it don't fire navigated or any other event that browser control has it just go strait from app to media player. Only event that I'm able to get is navigate from app from which so basically  I can't get any event on which I can check this.

Comment: ScriptNotify is a method of the Web browser control which gets fired for any action that you take on it. e.g. a link click or a press and hold action etc. If clicking on a link with an audio/video is the only thing you are doing in your browser control, you may have this ScriptNotify method as an option.

Actually even i had done several manipulations, set several flags at several places and then checked in the ScriptNotify. Because, every click on the browser always takes you to script notify. So, you need to be sure that a link was clicked.

Comment: One addition. Navigate to youtube.com on a browser control. Click on a video link. Then click on the video play option. In this case, note that Browser navigation to a uri does not happen. All that happens is a java script functionality. So you need some script to handle this. ScriptNotify will just be fired whenever any script handling will happen. The opening of the media player is not directly controllable via c#. Javascript is what you should look into if you are trying to achieve this.